# Scale parts of the image in ImageView android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I need to scale the part of an imageView (say from x to y), rather than the whole image. The setscaleType() function happens to work for the whole image rather than on specific parts.
Please let me know if there is a way to do it in android.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it by two ways.

1. Create separate part of the image(photoshop)
2. Create new bitmap(rect) and draw it on new Canvas and play with it.

I will prefer you to go with 2 option.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to  try this now. Will come back and update the post.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

> public static Bitmap [createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29) (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int
>   width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)

Since: API Level 1

Returns an immutable bitmap from subset of the source bitmap, transformed by the optional matrix. It is initialized with the same density as the original bitmap.

**Parameters**

```
    source  The bitmap we are subsetting
    x   The x coordinate of the first pixel in source
    y   The y coordinate of the first pixel in source
    width   The number of pixels in each row
    height  The number of rows
    m   Optional matrix to be applied to the pixels
    filter  true if the source should be filtered. Only applies if the matrix contains more than just translation.
```

**Returns**

```
A bitmap that represents the specified subset of source
```

---

You can also [crop specific portion of image-in-android](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/15/crop-an-image-in-android/) and then use createBitmap to format the new cropped image.

---

### An example of using createBitmap:

```
public class bitmaptest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        // load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
        int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
        int newWidth = 200;
        int newHeight = 200;

        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // createa matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // rotate the Bitmap
        matrix.postRotate(45);

        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                          width, height, matrix, true);

        // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap
        // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        // set the Drawable on the ImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);

        // center the Image
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

        // add ImageView to the Layout
        linLayout.addView(imageView,
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                )
        );

        // set LinearLayout as ContentView
        setContentView(linLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. But  I went with changing rect in ondraw() which really worked well.